# How to use Rails postgresql connection raw.put_copy_data from string instead of a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I usually copy data into my postgres database in rails using the following import module.

In this case I am uploading a file that is ready for postgres copy command to take in.

```
module Import #< ActiveRecord::Base
  class Customer
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include EncodingSupport

  attr_accessor :file

  validates :file, :presence => true

  def process file=nil
    file ||= @file.tempfile
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('truncate customers')
    conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.checkout
    raw  = conn.raw_connection
    raw.exec("COPY customers FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',',  NULL ' ', HEADER true)")
    # open up your CSV file looping through line by line and getting the line into a format suitable for pg's COPY...
    data = file.open
    data::gets

    ticker = 0
    counter = 0
    success_counter = 0
    failed_records = []

    data.each_with_index do |line, index|
      raw.put_copy_data line
      counter += 1
    end
    # once all done...
    raw.put_copy_end
    while res = raw.get_result do; end # very important to do this after a copy
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.checkin(conn)
    return { :csv => false, :item_count => counter, :processed_successfully => counter, :errored_records => failed_records }
  end
```

I have another file now that needs to be formatted correctly though so I have another module that converts it from a text file to a csv file and trims out unnecessary content. Once it is ready I'd like to pass the data to the module above and have postgres take it into the database.

```
def pg_import file=nil
  file ||= @file.tempfile
  ticker = 0
  counter = 0
  col_order = [:warehouse_id, :customer_type_id, :pricelist_id]
  data = col_order.to_csv
  file.each do |line|
    line.strip!
    if item_line?(line)
      row = built_line
      data += col_order.map { |col| row[col] }.to_csv
    else
      line.empty?
    end
    ticker +=1
    counter +=1
    if ticker == 1000
      p counter
      ticker = 0
    end

  end

  pg_import data

end
```

My problem is the 'process' method returns data as

`"warehouse_id,customer_type_id,pricelist_id\n201,A01,0AA\n201,A02,0AC`

which means when I pass it to pg_import I can't iterate over the data. Because it expects it to be in the following format.

`[0] "201,A01,0AA\r\n",
[1] "201,A02,0AC\r\n",
[2] "201,A03,oAE\r\n"`

What command can I use to convert the string data so that I can iterate over it in the

`data.each_with_index do |line, index|
  raw.put_copy_data line
  counter += 1
end`

??

Probably has a really simple solution but just expecting to not be able to use the put_copy_data without having a file to iterate over...

Comment: OK so I was able to achieve the change with `data = data.split("\n").drop(1)` to make it an array that looks like what's coming out of the file. However when I loop nothing is going into the database so I am suspecting it is the `FROM STDIN` part. The `.drop(1)` was to get rid of the header line.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with this process before and within the loop.

```
data = CSV.parse(data)
data.shift

data.each_with_index do |line, index|
  line = line.to_csv
  raw.put_copy_data line
  counter += 1
end
```

Converted the string into an array of arrays with csv. Shifted to get rid of the header row. That allows me to iterate over the arrays. Grab an array and convert that array from an array back into a csv string and then pass it into the database.